# MVVMCross: View (Android layout) doesn't load

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I tried to use the MVVMCross following the [TipCalc](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566270/MvvmCross-TipCalc-Step-1-Creati) example but my View doesn't load. I can see the Activity label but the layout doesn't show up, with the following application output:

---

```
Forwarding debugger port 8973
Forwarding console port 8974
Detecting existing process
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/MVX.DroidWUL.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/Cirrious.CrossCore.Droid.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/Cirrious.CrossCore.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/System.Windows.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/Cirrious.MvvmCross.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/PCLCoreMVX.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/System.Net.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/System.Xml.Serialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/MVX.DroidWUL/files/.__override__/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Localization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Core.dll [External]
[ApplicationPackageManager] cscCountry is not German : LUX
[mono] WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
[mono] Using default runtime: v2.0.50727
[monodroid-gc] GREF GC Threshold: 46800
[MonoDroid] Xamarin/Android Trial Mode Active
[ApplicationPackageManager] cscCountry is not German : LUX
Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External]
[ApplicationPackageManager] cscCountry is not German : LUX
Loaded assembly: System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Xml.dll [External]
[mvx]   0.05 Setup: PlatformServices start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.05 Setup: PlatformServices start
[mvx]   0.70 Setup: Bootstrap actions
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.70 Setup: Bootstrap actions
[mvx]   0.82 Setup: StringToTypeParser start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.82 Setup: StringToTypeParser start
[mvx]   0.84 Setup: ViewModelFramework start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.84 Setup: ViewModelFramework start
[mvx]   0.85 Setup: PluginManagerFramework start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.85 Setup: PluginManagerFramework start
[mvx]   0.89 Configuring Plugin Loader for Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.PluginLoader
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.89 Configuring Plugin Loader for Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.PluginLoader
[mvx]   0.89 Ensuring Plugin is loaded for Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.PluginLoader
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.89 Ensuring Plugin is loaded for Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.PluginLoader
[mvx]   0.90 Setup: App start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.90 Setup: App start
[mvx]   0.91 Setup: ViewModelTypeFinder start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.91 Setup: ViewModelTypeFinder start
[mvx]   0.92 Setup: ViewsContainer start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.92 Setup: ViewsContainer start
[mvx]   0.93 Setup: ViewDispatcher start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.93 Setup: ViewDispatcher start
[mvx]   0.95 Setup: Views start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.95 Setup: Views start
[mvx]   1.15 Setup: CommandCollectionBuilder start
mvx:Diagnostic:  1.15 Setup: CommandCollectionBuilder start
[mvx]   1.16 Setup: NavigationSerializer start
mvx:Diagnostic:  1.16 Setup: NavigationSerializer start
[mvx]   1.21 Setup: LastChance start
mvx:Diagnostic:  1.21 Setup: LastChance start
[mvx]   1.53 Setup: Secondary end
mvx:Diagnostic:  1.53 Setup: Secondary end
[mvx]   1.62 Null Extras seen on Intent when creating ViewModel - this should not happen - have you tried to navigate to an MvvmCross View directly?
mvx:Error:  1.62 Null Extras seen on Intent when creating ViewModel - this should not happen - have you tried to navigate to an MvvmCross View directly?
[mvx]   1.63 ViewModel not loaded for view CalenderWUL
mvx:Warning:  1.63 ViewModel not loaded for view CalenderWUL
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

From that level of detail, no idea

The problem is clearly somewhere in the initialisation of `CalendarWUL` - whatever that is. But I can't diagnose it from that.

Some things you could try:

- does the completed sample (using a more up to date version of the code) run from: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/TipCalc
- do the latest released binaries work - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Binaries/
- or do older versions work (from that same folder)
- does the complete video walkthrough help - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGup08cz7LM&list=PLR6WI6W1JdeYSXLbm58jwAKYT7RQR31-W (there are several other walkthroughs on that same playlist)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just for the simple trial to see the decoupling and binding of View and Model-ViewModel using MVX, i created [this simple solution](https://www.dropbox.com/s/erjomp76h8mdnxq/MVX.zip), where only Android view and PCL are implemented. I think i followed the same steps as in Tip calc but still couldn't have success.

Comment: So I wasted 30 minutes of my life... I downloaded your sln, I fixed up your PCL so it said Profile104, I noticed that half of your libs came from some desktop directory and half from some nuget packages - changed them all to the nuget package, then I hit F5 and ... http://i.imgur.com/o9eRbe2.png - I suspect you are just mixing assemblies from different builds. I won't be helping further with this type of question - there's plenty of material on-line for Mac and PC - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/NP1%20days%20of%20MvvmCross

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the assembly problem (At least, now i know  that the application was fine other than the assemblies).
I used the Nuget for the Json and for others assemblies downloaded from github repo, as i was having problem using the NuGet properly.
Sorry for my mistakes, and i'm just a student learning rather than a pro.
Thanks again for your time and suggestion.

Comment: No worries - I just don't have time to assist with the basic stuff - sorry. I am trying to make it easier by posting articles, videos, etc - but I can't afford to do much more. Have fun out there :)